# An error occurred while updating the entries. xx.xxx Out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a table with the column

name: variant_markup
datatype: numeric(4,3)

I try to put value 10.000 into it

And I get the Error

An error occurred while updating the entries

10.000 Out of range

It shouldn't be, and I have other columns with same data type and the same process to add a number in, and they don't complain!

The code:

```
decimal strippedMarkRate = decimal.Round(0, 3);
        if (MarkUpTextBox.Text != string.Empty)
            strippedMarkRate = decimal.Round(decimal.Parse(toolbox.removeChars(MarkUpTextBox.Text)), 3);

variant_markup = strippedMarkRate;
```

toolbox.removeChars function just removes any character that isn't a digit or a decimal point from the box, is there a way to do this with regex by anychance?

Comment: Your code doesn't involve `variant_markup`, so I'm a little confused as to where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert 10.000 then your data type needs to be defined as numeric(**5**,3).  The first digit in the numeric type declaration is the maximum number of digits in the number (precision).  In the case of 10.000, there are 5.

[decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

> decimal [ (p[ ,s] )] and numeric[ (p[ ,s] )]
>
> ...
>
> **p (precision)**    The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision
>   must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The
>   default precision is 18.
>
> **s (scale)**   The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p.
>   Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default
>   scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based
>   on the precision.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your remove chars isn't doing what you need it to? As to you last question, it would probably be faster to remove the disallowed chars with a foreach statement like so:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(char c in value)
{
      if(char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.')
      {
          sb.append(c);
      }
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Wouldn't I get an exception when trying to parse to a decimal if it wasn't doing what it's suppose to????